# NGINX - Downstream and Upstream header Values

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx reverse-proxy.

I have a website that does not like a proxy_pass. I want to look at all the header details, downstream and upstream, to determine what is being received and passed to the upstream website.

I understand this information would need to be logged and reviewed. I am having a problem determining what information I need to log (field names, etc.)

If I can see the downstream and upstream information I can determine what information I need to change upstream.

Any and all information is very welcome, Pete.